# Where do i find a list of dummy credit card numbers?

Tags: credit-card

I have a very simple JS check and i am looking for a list of dummy cc numbers which i can exclude.
Just for mastercard AmEx and Visa

```
var dummyCCArr = new Array();
dummyCCArr=["5105105105105100","4111111111111111", "4012888888881881", "378282246310005","5454545454545454","5431111111111111",]; 

if(jQuery.inArray(cardNo, dummyCCArr)!=-1){
        ccErrorNo = 5;
        return false;
    }
```

Any links?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different credit card companies use different checksums to do an initial validation of the card (make sure it's a valid format for that brand of card).

You can find info [here](https://www.businessyeti.com/Apps/CreditCardGenerator/) on the different checksums used

EDIT: To clarify, I would perhaps validate using this kind of approach, it can't prove the fact that it is a valid credit card, just a valid format.

Comment: tx, i do validate on the prefix, Length, and Check Digit i just wanted to add the dummy part.

Answer (score 2):

From the looks of it, you are in trouble! Because I just found a valid CC number generator. (Not tested though).

Maybe apart from the very basic ones, you'll actually have to validate a CC after all.

http://mediakey.dk/~cc/wp-dyn/credit-card-number-generator.php

Here is another link

http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Comment: tx for the links, i will add some of those numbers. hmm the CC number generator looks awesome (for this simple project in a bad way)